# How to highlight changes when comparing versions of a document in OS X?

Tags: macos, versions, document-management

I've been exploring the versions functionality of the new document model in Mac OS X 10.8. It's mostly similar to what was in Lion. In the title bar of a supported document choose "Browse all versions…" from the drop-down menu.

It seems handy enough, but how can you easily tell what has changed between each document without having to manually scan each line? I assumed there must be a feature to highlight the changes but I can't find it. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I'm quite sure the highlighting doesn't exist. Apple's documentation doesn't mention it either: [OS X Lion: About Auto Save and Versions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4753)
(I know it's from Lion)

Mountain Lion changes to Auto Save doesn't mention it either. [What's New in OS X v10.8](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011634-SW1) (Auto Save is mentioned under `AppKit`)